# NSLocale.preferredLanguages doesn't change when changing NSUserDefaults

Tags: swift, ios8, localization, internationalization

i have been researching this for days now.

i have a swift ready application , lately we decided to introduce localization, when i set the system language to the desired language , it works , but when i try to manually change the language it doesn't work.

what i have tried :

```
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(["ar"], forKey: "AppleLanguage")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

after i restart the app

`let lang = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("AppleLanguage")` does return ["ar"]

but

```
NSLocale.preferredLanguages()[0]
```

still returns ["en"]

and the application appears in the english version and locale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is named `AppleLanguages` (note the s at the end).

I'm sure you know, but localized apps don't need to perform custom language selection. It's best to leave it to iOS which lets users define their global international settings.

Comment: it actually worked :) , this makes me a little ashamed of myself :( . Thank you so much anyways